# Difference of increasing functions differentiable a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, bounded-variation

I'm working through Royden & Fitzpatrick's Real Analysis, in the beginning of section 6.3 it reads and I quote: "Lebesgue's theorem tells us that a monotone function on an open interval is differentiable almost everywhere. Therefore the difference of two increasing functions on an open interval also is differentiable almost everywhere."

For this to be true, it means that the difference of two increasing functions on an open interval is monotone, but I do not see how that is immediately obvious.

Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: No! It says the difference of two increasing functions is differentiable everywhere. It does not have to be monotone.

Comment: @JohnMa: Thx for your comment, then how does he arrive at that conclusion, and why does he place that statement right after restating the Lebesgue theorem?

Comment: Because this is an immediate consequence of that theorem. If $f_1, f_2$ are differentiable almost everywhere, then so is $f_1 - f_2$.

Comment: @JohnMa: Hmm, I'm sorry I don't quite see that. The theorem states 

"$f$ monotone $=>$ $f$ differentiable a.e." 

From this information the only way I can claim $f=f_1 - f_2$ is differentiable a.e. is by showing $f$ is monotone.

Comment: $f_1,f_2$ increasing $\Rightarrow f_1, f_2$ monotone $\Rightarrow f_1, f_2$ differentiable almost everywhere. So $f_1 - f_2$ is differentiable almost everywhere. (Which implications do you not understand?)

Comment: I do not understand $f_1,f_2$ differentiable a.e $=>$ $f_1-f_2$ differentiable a.e.

It seems that to use Lebesgue's theorem would be to claim $f_1-f_2$ monotone $=>$ $f_1-f_2$ differentiable a.e.

Comment: If $f_1$, $f_2$ are differentiable at $a$, then $f_1 - f_2$ is also differentiable at $a$ (nothing to do with measure theory). Also the set $\{a : f_1, f_2\text{ is differentiable at } a\}$ is of full measure.

Comment: Here is a harder problem.  If you understand this one you will certainly get it.  *Suppose $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of a.e  differentiable functions. Show that there is a set of measure zero $N$  so that $f_n'(x)$ exists for all integers $n$ and for all $x\not\in N$.*

Comment: @B.S.Thomson If $f_1, f_2$ are differentiable a.e., i.e., respectively differentiable on $A:=N_1^c, B:=N_2^c$, where $N_i$'s are null sets, then $f_1 + f_2$ is differentiable on $A\cap B$, where $(A\cap B)^c$ is a null set by subadditivity of measure. Is this the correct detailed explanation?

Comment: @Mike Kindly check my above comment as I am learning as well. I can't seem to mention user99914. x-D